# Trying to run function inside MAP

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to run a function inside of my map... but the map only runs the function not the rest of the code.

**Edit:** i realized i haven't really explained the situation. I am trying to run this.math so that i get a new unique value for each of my calls.

```js
math = () => {
  var add = this.state.add + 1
 this.setState({
   add: add
 })
 console.log(add)
}

var projects = this.state.key.map((key) => {
  this.math()
  ` &filter[where][or][${this.state.add}][id]=${key.fk}`
})
```

Comment: You probably want your function to actually return something.

Comment: What does `this.math()` do or return  and what are you expecting the template literal to do? `map()` expects a return also. Not clear what your expectations are here

Comment: I don't know what `this.math()` is doing, but it is completely unassociated with the string after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Thank you so much for the insight. Also this is my first post on stack overflow. Below you will find my fix i hope this helps others in the future.

```
       var projects = this.state.key.map((key) => {this.math() 
    return (`&filter[where][or][${this.state.add}][id]=${key.fk}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Running a function on a template is done without invoking the function using ().

See [https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/template_strings](http://Tagged%20template%20strings)

Try removing them like this:

```
var projects = this.state.key.map((key) => {
  return this.math` &filter[where][or][${this.state.add}][id]=${key.fk}`
})
```

Comment: would still need a `return` since it's inside `{}` block